# Create new WPF page which is subset of current page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating a WPF application which behaves like a 'Windows Wizard', when I press a button in **MainWindow** it should navigate to say **Page2**.

For **Page2** I added a new WPF page from VisualStudio.
 Is there any way for this new page to inherit some attributes from main window, like background,dimension,title,etc since most of the attributes are same.

Comment: You can give a style of Window using Resource Dictionary

Comment: I'd probably have a single window where multiple `UserControl`s are loaded in/swapped when the user navigates. This way you can have standard forward/back buttons and you can create an interface for each sub-window that provides logic to decide whether the forward/back are available etc. This way your window doesn't change and you only need to create a single "wizard" window

Comment: @Charleh How can I do that. I am using designer in VS2013 to create GUI, doesn't the elements on all the pages show overlapped on designer.

Comment: I'd be using an MVVM framework for it - but you'd just need a single window with a placeholder area. You then create a `UserControl` for each 'page'. When the window loads, you create an instance of the first `UserControl` and place it into the placeholder in the window. The buttons for next/prev etc can live on the window, but the content of each page lives inside the `UserControl` making it easier to manage the transitions between the windows + ensuring that all the 'parts' are separate. I'd consider looking at MVVM frameworks though if you are serious about WPF unless it's a very simple app

Comment: Each UserControl can implement an `IPageableWizard` interface or something of that ilk with properties such as `CanMoveNext`, `CanMovePrev` and methods or events such as `MoveNext`/`OnMoveNext`, `MovePrev`/`OnMovePrev` to handle state during transitions. The window or some sort of controller would be responsible for the loading/unloading/changing of windows using the interface to query each page to determine whether transitions are allowed/happening. This makes it much easier to add new pages as your basic 'framework' is there and you just hook into it

Answer (score 2):

you can use ResourceDictionaries for stuff like Color Attributes etc.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="LimeColor">#FFA4C400</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource LimeColor}" x:Key="Lime" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourDictionary.xaml" /> 
</Application.Resources>
```

For the correct Source see: [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Page and Window**
for example:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource Lime}">
```

Or you can define Styles and Templates in WPF for any ControlTypes.

For further information : [Control Customization on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278068(v=vs.95).aspx)